# Variable, which is an ID JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable called `counter`, which represents the `id` of an element.

How would I select this variable's value e.g. the `div` with the `id`, which is the value of the variable, in jQuery?

```
counter = counter + 1;
$('<a> </a>').hover(  function() {
    $(#/*id is the value of variable counter*/).
}
```

Comment: you mean like `$("#" + counter.toString())`?

Comment: A side note: `id` cannot be just a number (in `html4`)

Comment: counter is only numbers

Comment: you can give unique class name to that div n get the id of that div with attr.

Comment: @zerkms mhm let m,e check

Comment: What is `$('<a> </a>').hover(` supposed to do?

Comment: @zerkms it is only a number and it works in all browsers

Comment: @undefined I have a list of textual coordinates, if i hover one of the textual coordinates it should highlight the specific marker in the image

Comment: @downvoter I think this is a legit question, no?

Comment: Check my answer - you can set attribute with desired number.

Comment: @piotr i will check all answers carefully in 5 mins and happily accept the one, which is working for me best

Comment: @zerkms In HTML5, id's can contain just numbers. Although, I agree browser support is usually very important. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#"+variable)
```

That's it! You can combine it even different way, because as mentioned in comments it shouldn't be number.

```
$("#element_"+variable)
```

etc.

---

Or by attribute

```
$("a[data-value="+counter+"])
```

And HTML part

```
<a data-value="1"></a>
```